# How to determine whether a street or address exists near geographic coordinates?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe8

My program calculates new coordinates in WGS84 for google (longitude and latitude). How can you verify whether under these coordinates is a street or an address.

Comment: You are looking for reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is provided by the `TGeocoder` class - documentation can be found here :

Class : [TGeocoder](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Sensors.TGeocoder)

> Used for handling geocoding and reverse geocoding.
>
> Geocoding is the process of transforming geographic data like address, zip codes into geographic coordinates. Reverse geocoding is the process for transforming geographical coordinates into other geographical data, such as address. The Initialize procedure must be used before using TGeocoder for the first time through the Current property. The Supported function determines whether the geocoding can be realized. Authorized determines whether the application is authorized to use the service.

The method you likely want : [TGeocoder.GeocodeReverse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Sensors.TGeocoder.GeocodeReverse)

> Requests the address matching the specified geographic coordinates.

To create an instance of the `TGeocoder` class specific to your platform/device, you use the `.Current` class property [as described in the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Location_Sensors_%28iOS_and_Android%29#Use_Reverse_Geocoding).

```
// ... in your class
private       
    FGeocoder: TGeocoder;
    procedure OnGeocodeReverseEvent(const Address: TCivicAddress);
```

and then

```
// Setup an instance of TGeocoder
if not Assigned(FGeocoder) then
begin
  if Assigned(TGeocoder.Current) then
    FGeocoder := TGeocoder.Current.Create;
  if Assigned(FGeocoder) then
    FGeocoder.OnGeocodeReverse := OnGeocodeReverseEvent;
end;
```

Comment: Does the `OnGeocodeReverse` fire when there's nothing to geocode (e.g. with empty fields of the passed `TCivicAddress` structure) ? Or how does it indicate this situation ? Err, and how does it indicate error in general (if it's asynchronous) ? It makes me feel that this class is missing a few things. [just curious, this seems to be the way to go :)]

Comment: @TLama  actually, it looks like this is just an abstract class... I don't see where it is actually implemented anywhere.  Maybe it isn't.  If I can't find  anything else I'll probably delete this answer.

Comment: It seems you can get the (default ?) implementation (for the current platform ?) by `TGeocoder.Current` property ([`source`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Location_Sensors_(iOS_and_Android)#Use_Reverse_Geocoding)).

Comment: @TLama yes, that makes sense now.  In any case, `OnGeocodeReverse` gets fired whenever the implementer decides to do it - this seems left up to the descendent class to decide.  The windows default implementation actually doesn't implement reverse geocoding (the implementation is empty but for a `// do nothing` comment).  I don't have source for the mobile units to say how it works for android...